# Does the Universe itself move to any direction on top of expansion?

Tags: cosmology, reference-frames, universe, space-expansion, big-bang

So the universe expands right, but does this expansion move to any direction in hyperspace as an expanding cluster of matter somewhere?

It's like if you would explode a bucket of paint under the. river, it would expand from center, but the river flow would carry the expansion somewhere as well.

[image]

Comment: move in reference to what?

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid you won't like my answer and my reputation won't increase.
I can't do better than copying a quotation I already posted about two
weeks ago:

> Philosophy is written in this grand book, the universe, which stands
>   continually open to our gaze. But the book cannot be understood unless
>   one first learns to comprehend the language and read the letters in
>   which it is composed. It is written in the language of mathematics,
>   and its characters are triangles, circles, and other geometric figures
>   without which it is humanly impossible to understand a single word of
>   it; without these, one wanders about in a dark labyrinth.

(Galileo, *The Assayer* (1622))

As you can see, it's four centuries old, but it's always true,
especially when it comes to subjects like the present one. But I would
add some comments.

The first is: please don't interpret Galileo's words as meaning that
physics reduces to or is founded on mathematics. I don't believe that.
In our case (expansion of space) observations were and are
fundamental. The point is that we can't understand what's happening in
the universe solely by building pyramids of words. Our common language
is unable to cope with those matters. Mathematics is a special
creation of humankind, which allows us to think on a higher level than
is allowed by common language. Moreover common language is ambiguous:
words like "space" or "expansion" don't have a precise meaning. We may
believe they have as far as we use them about everyday facts. But
universe and all that are completely out of our thinking habits.
Mathematics forces us to precisely define things, to draw rigorous
conclusions from clearly stated premises - so it's a marvelous
*thinking instrument* (as I like to say). It expands our capabilities
and at the same time keeps them under control.

The second comment is that we have a special ability to build word
sequences we believe have a meaning just because they are grammatically
correct. An example is "what is outside?" The worst thing is that we
are frequently tempted to deal with such questions not as meaningless
but as deep philosophical ones. When someone tries to object as to
what such a question might mean, he often receives the answer: "the
fact that your physics can't answer it is a proof that there are
questions your science can't even think." (If the last sentence
reminded you a most famous one: "there are more things in heaven and
earth Horatio than are dreamt of in your philosophy", it was intended.)

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes. It moves forward in temporally.
2. Re: spatially. Does it matter? If it was special relativity posits that we wouldn't be able to detect it.

Comment: So we don't know for sure? So for example another universe might be drawing us with it's gravity but we would never know?

Comment: Well that would be an acceleration and that can be measured, albeit a very difficult one to measure, particularly as we can't completely account for all the mass in the universe.

Answer (score 1):

As Paul Childs pointed out, it doesn't matter. What he means by this is that your question isn't physically meaningful. If there does not exist a way to answer a physics question, then it's not a physics question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no hyperspace with a direction for the universe to move in. Space simply expands in all directions so that galaxies get further and further apart. The universe is not exploding into something else. On a cosmological scale, the matter in the universe is evenly distributed, not clustered somewhere.

Comment: What do you mean, there is obviously space beyond visible universe, otherwise, where is it expanding to?

Comment: @PokemonMasta It's expanding into itself.

Comment: In modern cosmological theories there is no empty space beyond the visible universe. There is just more universe, filled with galaxies. It is all expanding, but not *into* anything. If you learn the mathematics, you will understand how this can be!

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expansion_of_the_universe

Comment: As an example imagine space time being the surface of a balloon. As it is inflated it expands. Points on the balloon get further apart.

Answer (score 0):

This might remains a big philosophical question but not a physical one. In very layman words we are already dealing with an immense vastity and already cast description well beyond visible and observable universe. Further away we'll never be able to test anything. A relieve to this can be a rock solid cosmology, pointing to an already infinite universe.

In this scenario there is no needing to place something within a big arena, though I suspect we will always tend to do so.

All other circumstances let open the question "what is outside?". One can say more or less everything but, even more dramatically then before, no hypothesis will be susceptible of being tested.
And if one say there is simply nothing out, we will ask ourself other philosophical questions such as "what is nothing", or better "if nothing can even exist".